# Smaato and iAds combined

Tags: ios, iad

i am willing to implement iAds by default in my application which is now correctly showing, and also I have properly implemented Smaato's SDK.

Is there any method to show by default iAds and when this don't serves me an ad, then pull from Smaato?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example for this within the Smaato Ad SDK. When you open the folder iSomaDemoApp/iPhone you will see the files
SOMAiAdBannerView.h and
SOMAiAdBannerView.m
which implement the behavior you are looking for.

The usage is the same as a default SOMABannerView, but you can have a look at iAdViewController.m in the same directory to see an example.